# Remove Empty Entry from EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, enums, html-helper

I want to remove the Blank/Empty entry from my EnumDropDownListfor - have searched online and tried below links but nothing seems to work

[Remove blank/empty entry at top of EnumDropDownListFor box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158163/remove-blank-empty-entry-at-top-of-enumdropdownlistfor-box)

[Remove blank entry from EnumDropDownListFor(...)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269607/remove-blank-entry-from-enumdropdownlistfor)

Code in View:-

```
<td>
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Actions, new { @id = "actions", @class = "form-control" })
</td>
```

Code in Model:-

```
[Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Select an Action")]
    [Display(Name = "Actions")]
    public ItemTypes Actions { get; set; }
```

Enum in Controller:-

```
 public enum ItemTypes
    {
        Add = 1,
        Remove = 2
    }
```

Dropdown renders as below:-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your problem is the enum defined with starting index of 1:

```
public enum ItemTypes
{
    Add = 1,
    Remove = 2
}
```

Since no enumerator specified with index 0 inside above enum, the helper includes the zero index inside `SelectListItem` collection list, hence an empty option shown as default selected item (remember that both enum and collections use zero-based indexing, hence first item has index of zero).

Either you could define an enumerator with index 0 to set default selected value:

```
public enum ItemTypes
{
    Nothing = 0,
    Add = 1,
    Remove = 2
}
```

Or use standard `DropDownListFor` helper using other property defined from `SelectListItem` to bind enum values:

**Model**

```
public List<SelectListItem> ActionList { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
ActionList = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ItemTypes)).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x, Value = x }).ToList();
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Actions, Model.ActionList, new { @id = "actions", @class = "form-control" })
```

Reference:

[C# Enumeration Types (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/enumeration-types)